# Select2 - How to set value of id string

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, jquery-select2

I have some problem, with **select2**, I want to send value of `id` integer, but there's problem,
here my code

**controller**

```
$user = User::select('user_reg_no as id', 'user_name as text')->get()->toArray();
return response()->json($user);
```

**js**

```
function get_user() {
    res = $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: SITE_URL,
        async: false
    });
    return res.responseJSON;
}

var data_user = get_user();

$('#user').select2({
    data: data_user
});
```

and then when the `id` is `0000345`
but in **select2** become `345`, how to handle this?

Comment: Can you post sample json response you get from controller?

Comment: `[{"id":"","text":""},{"id":256,"text":"Darth Vader"},{"id":289,"text":"Zero"
}]`
and actually the code is 00256 and 00289

Comment: Can you check your table? I think on the table itself it is saved as 256 instead of 00256.

Comment: Please post your migration file

Comment: You can append a alphabet to the id so that it will be considered as string and when you get the data back from user you can trim it off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `id` in your `JSON` response is an integer so it will remove the preceding zeros.

**Option 1**

Manually build `JSON` response and then send the response from your controller

**Option 2**

Cast directly the attributes using `$cast` array in `Model` like,

```
protected $casts = [
   'id' => 'string',
];
```

Comment: Option 1 and 2 both doesnt work as JSON data is transferred as string. If the response has `application/json`, the system parses it and converts it to integer.